# C++ Class object as argument in other class function

Tags: c++, function, class, object, parameter-passing

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2015.
GameManager.h and Input.h both give me a ***syntax error: identifier 'Player'***. This happens because I want to **give an object of type 'Player' as an argument** to functions in these two Header files and their appropriate C++ Files.
How do I fix that? For further information I have provided my code.
main.cpp:

```
#include "GameManager.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "Player"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int maxPlayerCnt = 10;
static Player p1, p2, morePlayers[maxPlayerCnt];

int main()
{
    GameManager game;
    game.Game(p1, p2, morePlayers);
    return 0;
}
```

It creates an object of type GameManager and 3 objects of type Player.
GameManager.h:

```
#include "Player.h"

class GameManager
{
public:
    void Game(Player p1, Player p2, Player morePlayers[]);
};
```

GameManager.cpp:

```
#include "GameManager.h"

void GameManager::Game(Player p1, Player p2, Player morePlayers[])
{
    int playerCnt = 0;
    Input input;
    input.getPlayerDetails(playerCnt, p2);
    input.getMorePlayerDetails(playerCnt, morePlayers);

}
```

It creates an object of type Input to use further functions and will get more code, once I figure this problem out. And then calls to functions with specific arguments it gets from main.cpp
Input.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Input
{
public:
    Input();
    void getPlayerDetails(int &playerNum, Player p);
    void getMorePlayerDetails(int &playerNum, Player p[]);
};
```

It includes everything Input.cpp needs and initializes the funcitons

Input.cpp:

```
#include "Input.h"

void Input::getPlayerDetails(int &playerNum, Player p)
{
    playerNum++;
    string currentName;
    char currentSymbol;
    cout << "Player " << playerNum << ", what is your name?\n";
    cin >> currentName;
    p.setName(currentName);
    cout << currentName << " what is your symbol?\n";
    cin >> currentSymbol;
    p.setSymbol(currentSymbol);
}

void Input::getMorePlayerDetails(int &playerNum, Player p[])
{
    int plNum = playerNum;
    if (playerNum >= 12)
        cout << "You can't get another player!\n";
    else
    {
        //getPlayerDetails(p[playerNum - 2], (plNum - 2));
    }
}
```

It for now has all the functions needed and both get an object of type Player. And the second function is not quite done now. But that is not important.
Player.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Player
{
private:
    string _name;
    char _symbol;
public:
    Player();
    void getName();
    void setName(string name);
    void setSymbol(char symbol);
    };
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"    
Player::Player()
{

}

void Player::getName()
{
    cout << "I have no name!\n";
}

void Player::setName(string name)
{
    _name = name;
}

void Player::setSymbol(char symbol)
{
    _symbol = symbol;
}
```

If you can help me, I would be pleased to see your response.

Comment: Can you show `Player.h`?

Comment: You probably need to forward declare `Player` as `class Player` where the compiler is complaining about it.  In addition, you probably want to pass `Player` by reference so use `Player &p` instead of `Player p`

Comment: One guess is that you include some of the other headers in Player.h, and create a circular include chain.

Comment: I tried to pass Player by reference. But first of all I can not pass an array by reference and even with the normal Player p1 and p2 I could not fix the problem

Comment: I know it's not the solution, but maybe you use should std::vector<Player> for morePlayers variable. And pass it by const reference (const std::vector<Player> &vp ).

Can you show your main.cpp includes ?

Comment: I would like to try that, but I have limitations from what I can use and I must not use vectors.